# Generate Func<TParam1, TParam2, TService> factories in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

I have some services registered in the container. And some type which has dependencies on this service **and** short living arguments. For example:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IService1 svc1, IService2 svc2, int entityId) { }
}
```

What I want to have is some way to auto generate factories for creating such objects without manually coding each factory. I can use `Func<int, Foo>` or create some `IFooFactory` (with `CreateFoo(int entityId)` method) and I want to let Simple Injector to auto generate implementation of this factory (in some generic way for any count of arguments).

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you supply us with more context about this class `Foo`. What kind of class is this? Is this an entity, like `Customer` or `Order`?

Comment: Currently I just want to understand is it possible in SimpleInjector (such functionality) or not. For example, AutoFac support such feature for Func<..> - http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html. Considering method injection - in such case all dependencies will be explicit. In case if some dependency will be added - I will need to change all invocation of this method. Can I avoid it?

Comment: As an example - I want to have some <code>MessageProcessor</code> which have several methods to process message and several dependencies but works with concrete message only (I don't want to pass it in the every method again and again)

Comment: It's seems to me that you have a design problem. You might want to create a new SO question with a detailed description of your design. If you post a link to the question here, I'll do my best to feedback on that design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [AutomaticParameterizedFactoryExtensionsTests class](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/SimpleInjector.CodeSamples.Tests.Unit/AutomaticParameterizedFactoryExtensionsTests.cs) from the SimpleInjector github page. It has a test method that explains how to use the AutomaticParameterizedFactoryExtensions, which seems to be what you are asking for.

This class is in the SimpleInjector.CodeSamples project in the source code.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this sample do it. Unfortunately, I didn't find such example in the documentation that's why I have asked this question. Thanks.

Comment: The reason this is not in the documentation is bevause we like to discourage developers from doing this.

Answer (score 2):

DI libraries are built to create object graphs of long lived services. You are trying to abuse your container to build a short-lived class. Short-lived objects like entities, messages and DTOs are often called [newables](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) because you should new them by hand, and not let your composition root or container auto-wire them for you.

If this `Foo` is an entity, dependencies [should not be injected into the entity's constructor](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/14/injecting-services-into-entities/). Method injection should be used instead; an entity has multiple domain methods and those methods should specify the dependencies they need. The component that calls that domain method can have those dependencies injected into its constructor. At runtime, you can pass those dependencies on to the entity's method.

Mixing runtime data with compile time dependencies into the constructors of classes has many downsides. For instance, it makes your object graph hard to verify, and this certainly holds for injecting `Func<TParam1, TParam2, Entity>`. Take for instance a class that takes in two parameters of the same type, such as `public Bar(IService1, int a, int b)` with the corresponding `Func<int, int, Bar>` method injected into consumers. But what if `Bar` is changed to `public Bar(IService1, int b, int a)` (with `a` and `b` swapped)? In that case the code will fail at runtime; neither the compiler, nor our DI library will ever be able to detect this for us.